# access multiple output array of python in bash

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that print out 3 different lists. How can I access them. For example:

```
python out:
[1,2,3,4][a,b,c,d][p,q,r,s]
```

Now in bash I want to access them as:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[a,b,c,d]
list3=[p,q,r,s]
```

So far, I tried something like:

```
x=$(python myscript.py input.csv)
```

Now, If I use `echo $x` I can see the above mentioned list: `[1,2,3,4][a,b,c,d][p,q,r,s]`
How could I get 3 different lists? Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have write access to the Python script?

Comment: Yes, I do have the write access to the python script.

Answer (score 1):

The Python output does not match the bash syntax. If you can not print the bash syntax directly from the Python script you will need to parse the output first.

I suggest using the `sed` command for parsing the output into bash arrays:

`echo $x | sed 's|,| |g; s|\[|list1=(|; s|\[|list2=(|; s|\[|list3=(|;s|\]|)\n|g;'`

#### Command explanation

```
sed 's|,| |g;       # replaces `,` by blank space
     s|\[|list1=(|; # replaces the 1st `[` by `list1=(`
     s|\[|list2=(|; # replaces the 2nd `[` by `list2=(`
     s|\[|list3=(|; # replaces the 3rd `[` by `list3=(`
     s|\]|)\n|g;'   # replaces all `]` by `)`
```

The output would be something like:

```
list1=(1 2 3 4)
list2=(a b c d)
list3=(p q r s)
```

At this point, the output are not actual lists. To turn the output into bash commands, you can surround the whole command with `eval $(...)`, then the output will be evaluated as a bash command.

#### Putting all together:

```sh
$ eval $(echo $x | sed 's|,| |g; s|\[|list1=(|; s|\[|list2=(|; s|\[|list3=(|;s|\]|)\n|g;')
$ echo ${list1[@]}
1 2 3 4
$ echo ${list2[@]}
a b c d
$ echo ${list3[@]}
p q r s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: This line is a simple test that it works.
##: IFS='][' read -ra main_list <<< [1,2,3,4][a,b,c,d][p,q,r,s]

IFS='][' read -ra main_list < <(python myscript.py input.csv)

n=1
while read -r list; do
  [[ $list ]] || continue
  read -ra list$((n++)) <<< "${list//,/ }"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${main_list[@]}")

declare -p list1 list2 list3
```

Output

```
declare -a list1=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")
declare -a list2=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d")
declare -a list3=([0]="p" [1]="q" [2]="r" [3]="s")
```

---

As per Philippe's comment, a `for` loop is also an option.

```
IFS='][' read -ra main_list < <(python myscript.py input.csv)

n=1
for list in "${main_list[@]}"; do
  [[ $list ]] || continue
  read -ra list$((n++)) <<< "${list//,/ }"
done

declare -p list1 list2 list3
```

Comment: Instead of `while`, you can do `for list in "${main_list[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: @Philippe, thank you for the comment, will add that `for` loop.